# Trying to predict 5 target variables , each can contain any value from 0 to 8 in any combination using neural network in python keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to solve classification problem using neural network in python keras .I have 2000 sample points ,5 input features(M1 to M5) as float numbers, 6 output target variables(E1 to E6) as integers 0 to 8 in any combination of two targets as given below:

```html
df.head()

M1    M2      M3      M4      M5     E1    E2      E3      E4      E5      E6
7.637   15.269  38.758  54.881  67.54     1 2   0   0   0   0
7.330   14.800  38.100  53.900  66.80     1 0   6   0   0   0
7.200   14.500  38.000  53.900  66.50     0 0   6   0   0   8
7.040   14.200  37.900  53.800  66.20     7 0   0   0   5   0
6.840   13.800  37.700  53.700  65.80     0 2   0   4   0   0
```

I have tried following and several other ways,but I am not getting right prediction of classes

```html
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My results of prediction are far from actual results as shown below:

```html
Expected results of few samples of x_test

E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6
2   8   0   0   0   0
0   2   0   4   0   0
0   2   0   7   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   2
8   2   0   0   0   0

Predicted results of same samples of x_test
E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a classification problem right ? More like a multi regression problem. You want your network to return for each sample 6 linear values from 0 to something.

By writing :

```py
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You're trying to get 6 values capped from 0 to 1 (sigmoid), and you tell the network to use a binary crossentropy, which means he will try to match 0 and 1 to a linear value.
Now :

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You will give linear values (0 to infinity) and compare it with other linear values using the mean squared error.

If you want to ease the learning, you may want to change linear activation to a capped relu or something like that.

EDIT ------------------------------------------------

Ok, this is actually more complex than that, you want a multioutput multiclass network, one possible solution may be something like that :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

Input = tf.keras.layers.Input(5)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)(Input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(40)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(60)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)(x)
out_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x) 
out_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x) 
out_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x) 
out_4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x) 
out_5 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
out_6 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = Input, outputs = [out_1, out_2, out_3, out_4, out_5, out_6])
model.compile(loss = ['sparse_categorical_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy','sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])
```

The main problem in your case is that class aren't mutually exclusive, and have different possible values from 0 to 8.

There are several possibilities to handle such a problem, the way I propose the network will output sparse categorical value(0-8) for each class (6), and will compute the loss for each of those, and then will average on all of them.

Then, if that works the way you like, you will need to focus on the architecture above, it is a rather complex problem, that may need more layers.

And in order to train your network you need to give it like

```py
model.fit(x_train, [y_train[:,0], y_train[:,1], y_train[:,2], y_train[:,3], y_train[:,4], y_train[:,5]], batch_size=1)
```

So that each y_train for one class is (1921, 1) with for each class the interger value of the output.

NB : categorical_crossentropy is expecting each y_train as (1921, 9) for each class, you could use it using keras.utils.to_categorical() that will create a (1921, 6, 9) output and then give a list like `[y_train[:,0,:], y_train[:,1,:] ...]`

Comment: ,I have implemented your suggestion but got results in form of float numbers ranging from some negative floats to more than 8( 8 is maximum value), but my prediction should  have only positive discrete integers such as  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 not any float number between them.. Prediction should only come in form of classes above For all  6 output variables (columns)  (E1 to E6) , prediction should be 0 to 8 .Can you please suggest me any improvements.

Comment: ..When I fit your model with:  model.fit (x_train,y_train, epochs=10)   I get error  "Shapes (32, 6) and (32, 9) are not compatible". Shape of my data is like Y.shape  is (1921, 6) and  X.shape  is (1921, 5)    y_train .shape is  (1536, 6)   x_train .shape is    (1536, 5)  .I have  searched about this problem and it tells something about changing   loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'  to 'binary_crossentropy' but my problem is not binary ,rather eight discreet  classes( 0 to 8) ,in 6 output columns. I actually dont know what causes this error

Comment: My bad, the answer is not totally accurate, let me add something

Comment: y_train= tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=9)      y_train.shape  is  (1536, 6, 9) .Then implemented as you said .But still getting regression like output ,not making sense: [array([[0.7141538 , 0.01572046, 0.00876348, ..., 0.00975291, 0.04560132,0.13203469],[0.86025447, 0.00987785, 0.01876474, ... I tried simple,classification(like nearest neighbor) which gives somewhat better results, but not accurate enough,and accuracy score cannot be computed as it says multioutput multiclass not allowed. I dont know best solution to my problem. Can I show my csv file to you

Comment: ,,y_train= tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=9) y_train.shape is (1536, 6, 9) .Then implemented as you said .But still getting regression like output ,not making sense: [array([[0.7141538 , 0.01572046, 0.00876348, ..., 0.00975291, 0.04560132,0.13203469],[0.86025447, 0.00987785, 0.01876474, ... I tried simple,classification(like nearest neighbor) which gives somewhat better results, but not accurate enough,and accuracy score cannot be computed as it says multioutput multiclass not allowed. I dont know best solution to my problem. Can I show my csv file.

Comment: Have you tried without the to_categorical and using the sparse ?